# A sufficient condition for irreducibility of a $G$-variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group over a field $k$ and let $V$ be a variety on which $G$ acts.  Suppose $U\subset V$ is a closed, irreducible, $G$-stable subset which intersects every $G$-orbit non-trivially.  Does it follow that $V$ is irreducible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to assume $G$ itself to be irreducible. Also, do you really want $U$ to be $G$-stable? Then it seems that your assumptions already imply that $U=V$ (see below).

At least over algebraically closed field you could argue as follows: $G\times U$ is irreducible (this would need more care in case of an arbitrary base field) and maps, by your assumption, surjectively onto $V$ through $G\times U\hookrightarrow G\times V\to V$, so $V$ is irreducible as well.

Comment: Thank you for this argument.  You're right to say that I don't want $U$ to be $G$-stable.  My mistake.  Can you give a counter-example in the case that $G$ is not irreducible?

Comment: @Jared: You could take $G=V$ a nontrivial finite group acting on itself by translation, and $U$ any element of $G$.

Comment: Of course.  Thanks again.